# How to read an XML with libXML2 using no string functions?

Tags: c, xml, xsd, libxml2

Essentially, I have multiple XSD files for a file format, because it's the main method of configuring the program, so I need versions of it with English strings, versions with German strings, etc. And if the file says in its `<schema>` statement which XSD it's using, it seems like I should be able to go through it without ever making a string comparison.

e.g. I want to avoid doing this:

```
xmlNodePtr cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
if(!xmlStrncmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "settings"))
{
    // do things
}
```

Because the string "settings" will change depending on the xsd file used, it could be "paramètres" or "einstellungen," etc.  Typically this is done with a separate stings file, but it seems like the xsd has all the information needed to function as that strings file.

However, it's unclear if for example, if the nth attribute in an element is defined by the XSD as optional with a default value, will libxml2 tell me it's the nth attribute, and give it the default value, when I iterate over the properties in the node?

Similarly, it seems like there should be a way to find out that an element is the nth element in the `<xs:choice>` or the nth item in the `<xs:enumeration>` but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it.

e.g. in this enumeration:

```
<xs:restrict base="xs:string">
     <xs:enumeration value="glucose"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="fructose"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="sucrose"/>
<xs:restrict>
```

"glucose" would be 0, "fructose" 1, "sucrose" 2, etc in the order that they appear.

Is there a decent way to do this?

Comment: Even after formatting elements in your question as code so they appear, I still can't tell what you're asking.   It sounds like you're wishing for validation messages to reference indices rather than component names.  Is that it?  It's hard to know.   The phrase *nth attribute* makes no sense because attributes have no order, and *if the file says in its `<schema>` statement which XSD it's using, it seems like I should be able to go through it without ever making a string comparison* also is very hard to interpret.  Voting to close as unclear what you're asking until this is better explained.

Answer (score 1):

Your troubles stem from the design decision that you've made to maintain parallel XSDs with semantically identical components yet lexically different names.

### Don't do that.

It's a terrible design decision that'll undermine the benefits of a standard XML vocabulary.  Choose a naming convention, *including a single natural language*, and use it consistently.

Save I18N for the translation of *content* (see [Best Practices for XML Internationalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-i18n-bp/)), not *markup*.